# How to set verbosity/logger levels programmatically?

Tags: ros, rospy, logger, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Is there a way to set verbosity/logger levels programmatically (up to node levels if possible)? How?

I have looked at [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Logging) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole).
It seems that I should somehow use `log4cxx::Logger`, cmiiw, but still do not know exactly how?
Please help.

Thanks a lot.
PS: Hopefully, for both roscpp and rospy (+roslisp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43397/how-to-set-verbosity/logger-levels-programmatically?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-17**:
Related: https://answers.ros.org/question/197964/set-log-level-in-launch-file/?answer=350817#post-id-350817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Or simply add

```
 if( ros::console::set_logger_level(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, ros::console::levels::Debug) )
    ros::console::notifyLoggerLevelsChanged();
```

in your nodes constructor. Replace Debug with your required logger level.

Don't forget to

```
#include <ros/console.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [hvpandya](https://answers.ros.org/users/24274/hvpandya/) with karma: 76 on 2015-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do this quite often when writing new nodes in C++.  Usually what I do is place the following little snippet right after my call to `ros::init`

```
log4cxx::LoggerPtr my_logger =
           log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME);
my_logger->setLevel(
           ros::console::g_level_lookup[ros::console::levels::Debug]);
```

This will set the node's log level to Debug.  Then I comment it out after the node is sufficiently developed.  I have never really looked into doing this in `rospy` or `roslisp`, but would also be interested in figuring out how.

***EDIT***

I just realized that this is quite easy to do with `rospy` as well.  As documented [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Initializing_your_ROS_Node), you can simply pass the `log_level` argument to a call to `rospy.init_node()` e.g.

```
rospy.init_node('my_node', log_level=rospy.DEBUG)
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-10**:
For completeness: in roslisp you have the method `set-debug-level` to set the level of a specific logger.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-01-14**:
You should not use `g_level_lookup` to map the ROS debug level to the log4cxx log level. Instead use the log4cxx level directly. Besides the package must specify a dependency on log4cxx in its package manifest and the cpp file must include the necessary log4cxx header(s).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anybody stumbling upon this page, if you just want to set verbosity of packages as soon as they are launched by launchfiles, the easiest way is:

1. to `export ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE="/path/to/my/config/rosconsole.config"`
2. edit, for example with `vi /path/to/my/config/rosconsole.config` adding these lines:

> 

```
log4j.logger.ros=INFO

log4j.logger.ros.roscpp.superdebug=WARN

log4j.logger.ros.my_package_name=DEBUG
```

3. launch your launchfile in the same shell.

The package name must be the one who corresponds to `<node pkg="my_package_name" ...>` line in the launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) with karma: 96 on 2015-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4